# Representing truth regarding beliefs in prolog

Tags: prolog

How to make this (or something similar) work in Prolog:

```
belief(john,red(apple)).
belief(peter,red(apple)).
X :- belief(john,X), belief(peter,X).
```

And get `true.` for the following query (while consulting above):-

```
?- red(apple).
```

Comment: Could you explain in words why you want `red(apple)` to be true?

Comment: @Isabelle, I want to encode the rule that whatever both John and Peter believe, is true. And that belief of both is that apple is red. So I want the engine to infer that the apple is indeed red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog does not allow the *head* of a rule to be just a variable. The head must be a *nonvar* term, whose functor (i.e., name and arity) identifies the predicate being defined. So, a possible solution would be something like this:

```
true_belief(X) :-
  belief(john,  X),
  belief(peter, X).

belief(john,  red(apple)).
belief(peter, red(apple)).
```

Examples:

```
?- true_belief(red(apple)).
true.

?- true_belief(X).
X = red(apple).
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's useful to define a little helper to capture when all (relevant) persons believe something:

```
all_believe(Belief) :-
    belief(john, Belief),
    belief(peter, Belief).
```

Then you can define, for example:

```
red(Object) :-
    all_believe(red(Object)).

green(Object) :-
    all_believe(green(Object)).
```

And with your given set of beliefs you get:

```
?- red(apple).
true.

?- green(apple).
false.
```

This works. It requires you to define similar rules for any term that you want to use as a belief.

You can make this a bit shorter with macro definitions using `term_expansion`:

```
term_expansion(declare_belief(Belief),
               Belief :- all_believe(Belief)).
```

This means that every top-level definition in your source code of the form `declare_belief(Belief)` should be treated as if you had written `Belief :- all_believe(Belief)` instead (with the variable `Belief` substituted appropriately).

So now you can just write this:

```
declare_belief(red(_)).
declare_belief(green(_)).
```

and it will be treated exactly like the longer definitions for `red(Object)` and `red(Object)` above. You will still have to write this kind of declaration for any term that you want to use as a possible belief.